# mssql another way to write a query using IN?

Tags: sql-server-2005, coldfusion

I'm updating a web page search form.  The user selects the group names they want to search for.  And on the action page, lets say for simplicity sake, I end up with the following query:

```
select GroupName
from    groupTable 
where groupName in ('Motley Crue','Alvin and the Chipmunks')
```

Normally, this isn't a problem for me but in this case, the database field may also contain a string of names such as:

```
Big Dog's Chair,Purple Dragon,Just Johnny,Johnny Faster,Van Halen
```

I believe I will have to loop over each item in the database field with each item in my comma delimited list.  If that is the case, I do not know how to do this and I don't know what search terms to use in SO or google.  I could use some help.

Database:  MSSQL 2005
Coldfusion:  CF9

I leave work in a at 5:00CST so if you reply, I probably wont see it until tomorrow.

Comment: MySQL has EXISTS and NOT EXISTS functions that would allow you to execute a sub query in the WHERE clause, looking at google results for MSSQL looks that you could do the same as an alternative...

Comment: @AlexP  Do you have an example using MySQL so I'll know for general reference?  It might help me to recognize the MSSQL query solution if I'm able to find it from Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this wouldn't be as ideal as separating them out into multiple columns, but you could do

```
select GroupName
from groupTable 
where (groupName like '%Motley Crue%'
 or groupname like '%Alvin and the Chipmunks%'
)
```

Comment: if multiple rows contained say, "Purple Dragon", would each row be picked up?

Comment: Just tried your solution and it worked.  Now I just need to code the CF to loop.  I'll try to add that tomorrow.  But for now, your solution worked.  Thank you.  SO wont let me approve it just yet.

Answer (score 2):

Matt is on the right track but:

that solution may produce unexpected results if a group name is a sub-string of the group.  for example, say a user picked 'Pink'.  That query would also match 'Pink Floyd' or 'Big pink' or any other band containing Pink.

I assumed your form variable's name is "selectedGroups".  Change it to whatever it really is and it should work.

```
select
    groupName
from
    groupTable
where
    <!--- I thought I knew a more graceful way of doing this but it isn't coming to me --->
    <cfloop list = '#form.selectedGroups#' index = "i">
        groupName = '#i#' <!--- match the group if the column only contains one value --->
    or  groupName like '#i#,%' <!--- match the group if it is the first group in the list --->
    or  groupName like '%,#i#,%' <!--- match the group name if it is in the middle of the list --->
    or  groupName like '%,#i#' <!--- match the group name if it is the last group in the list --->
    #i neq listLast(form.selectedGroups) ? ' or ' : ''# <!--- add an or for the next value to search --->
    </cfloop>
```

Comment: Well, it may not be as graceful as you had hoped but it is far more graceful than the crazy loop I was attempting to do.  I'm scraping my loop and working with yours.  I've not seen the index loop done with a `#i neq listLast(form.selectedGroups) ? ' or ' : ''#` before.  What is that doing, checking to see if that is the last item in the list and if so, adding an OR to the sql query?

Comment: that last line is just an if statement, it has nothing to do with the loop control but without it the query would bomb if you had more than one item in your list.  That syntax is called a ternary if.  It isn't new, but it's new to CF9.  It's usually for simple if/else and although I didn't need an else I like the clean syntax of ternary over <cfif> and it's faster than iif. ternary syntax is: condition ? true : false. it could have been written <cfif i neq listLast(form.selectedGroups)> or </cfif>

Comment: Excellent explanation.  +1 for you, sir!

Comment: For small tables you could also use the `','+ ColumnName +',' LIKE '%something%'` trick. For larger tables, Travis' suggestion is more efficient - in terms of indexes.

Comment: You keep the loop, but use a single `OR` statement: `WHERE 1 = 0
<cfloop list="#form.selectedGroups#" index="grp">
   OR ','+ groupName +',' LIKE '%,#grp#,%'
</cfloop>`